# Pepper: use logger class in js

Tags: javascript, pepper, choregraphe

Is there any way to use Pepper logger functions in JavaScript like in Python to write in Choregraphe log?

The `console.log()` from JS doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alert()` instead of `console.log()` but this way it will pop-up the information on the tablet, not in the choregraphe log.

Other think you can do is to raise an event with a the message you want to log as a string. This event to be handled with a python script that logs the passed string with the Pepper's logger.

Comment: event is a good solution, or a service with a `log` function so you centralize all logs...